# snapshot.val().users.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```
database()
    .ref('/')
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
        var user = snapshot.val().users.filter(x => x.mail == mail)[0];

        if (user != undefined && user != null) 
        {
            ToastAndroid.show("User is there !", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        }
        else
        {
            //Add user
        }
```

I want to search this user with mail address and if the user is not there i will add it.But I get this error.

> TypeError: snapshot.val().users.filter is not a function. (In 'snapshot.val().users.filter(function (x) { return x.mail == mail; })', 'snapshot.val().users.filter' is undefined)

Comment: No! Stop! Don't do that! Use queries instead of downloading WHOLE DATABASE, this will give you a lot of trouble in the future. Also, I really hope you aren't doing it on the client side

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments NEVER try to load all data to filter it on the client side. You can use `orderByChild` query to filter on the database to a specific reference in `users` to get only the one with the email you search for. The code would look something like this:

```js
database()
    .ref('/users')
    .orderByChild('email')
    .equalTo(email)
    .limitToLast(1)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
        var user = snapshot.val()

        if (user != undefined && user != null) 
        {
            ToastAndroid.show("User is there !", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        }
        else
        {
            //Add user
        }
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `.startAt(email).endAt(email)` here, instead of `.equalTo(email)`?

Comment: Thx @Puff. You are right. Don't know what hit me when writing the answer. I will update the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see the `startAt(value).endAt(value)` quite regularly, and it works. I just hope together we can teach folks the more idiomatic way to accomplish the same. :)

Comment: It's realy strange. I have it also very often in my code. But don't know why. Maybe we developers like complicated solutions haha

Comment: This technically answers the question, but doesn't warn the asker that whole database with emails is exposed to the public

Comment: Thx for the hint. He could use the firestore rule `allow list: if request.query.limit <= 1;` so even if the user changes the code he could only get a single email from the database with each call. If he makes the query public or just for signed in users is up to him and the features he want's to have in his app.